# SQL Cast string as hyperlink

Tags: t-sql, hyperlink, casting

My source data come from Pervasive SQL and returned in Excel (as external data query).  I test the code in PCC.

My tables contains a file path and file name and when concatenated together I get a sting value.  I want to cast this string as a hyperlink value so that I don't have to convert it in Excel.

Select path + file as link from file_source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hyperlink data type in SQL Server.  You need to use a VARCHAR i.e. VARCHAR(100) to store the link and then get the application or excel to display it as a hyperlink.

See:
[How to change field type to hyperlink in SQL](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/75d5fe8a-737f-47d7-ab9b-f263ce65ecbc/how-to-change-field-type-to-hyperlink-in-sql?forum=sqldatabaseengine)